# std::condition_variable::notify_one() does not wake up a waiting thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

I have a code something like the following:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <future>

std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;
std::future<void> worker;

void worker_thread() {
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg{ mtx };
    // do something 1
  }
  cv.notify_one();

  // do something 2
}

int main() {
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lg{ mtx };
    worker = std::async(std::launch::async, worker_thread);      
    cv.wait(lg);
  }
  // do something 3
}
```

The main thread does not proceed to `// do something 3` and I can't understand why. I thought the line `cv.notify_one()` should be reached from the worker thread after `cv.wait(lg)` has been passed by the main thread, so there is no reason to hang.

The worker thread is responsible for some streaming data processing, while the main thread is mainly responsible for GUI event processing.

`// do something 1` is about some initialization that should be done inside the worker thread. The main thread should wait for the worker thread to finish it.

`// do something 2` is the main job of the worker thread.

`// do something 3` is the main job of the main thread.

Changing `cv.notify_one()` to `cv.notify_all()` didn't help.

Is this usage of condition variable correct?

Comment: The wait should be coupled to a predicate, as in e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Comment: Can't reproduce (on Linux/g++ 7.2.1).

Comment: Can't reproduce in VS2017.

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact code? Because it does not look it could possibly lose a notification here.

Comment: @Eric - True.  However the page linked to has an example that's not so great.  For starters, it does not use a scoped lock.

Comment: Where is your worker.get() ?

Comment: @JiveDadson True, i just wanted to find a reasonable example quickly, the main point is the predicate. The scoped_lock should be used for new code.

Comment: @Erik - Fair enough. I have a confession to make. I originally linked to that reasonable example in my answer. Then I decided rather quickly to write a reasonabler example based loosely on the OP's code. Speaking of which, if that answer meets with your approval, could I get a thumbs up on it? I live for thumbs up.

Comment: @JiveDadson, I have upvoted now.

Comment: @G.M.,@RustyX,@MaximEgorushkin, It actually worked just fine before I changed some contents inside "//do something 2". The only guess I could make was, due to that change, the compiler made some different optimization decisions, and that made some differences in context swapping timings, and that revealed a problem that was already in the original code. Is this usage of condition variable really correct? If it is, perhaps I should suspect compiler bug...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to backtrack on my original answer, and I apologize to Junekey for that. I misread the code, and concluded there was a race condition. I cannot reproduce the problem. We need an example that actually blocks forever on the cv.wait in order to figure out why it is doing so. Nevertheless, the code is incorrect if for no other reason than that it could get a spurious notification and pass through cv.wait before the worker_thread calls cv.notify. That rarely happens, but it does happen.

This code is more or less canonical:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>

std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool worker_done = false;  // <<< puts the "condition" in condition_variable

void worker_thread() {

    // do something 1

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg{ mtx };
        worker_done = true;  // ... and whatever
    }

    cv.notify_one();

    // do something 2
}

int main() {
    std::thread workman(worker_thread);
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lg{ mtx };
        while (!worker_done) {
            cv.wait(lg);
        }
    }
    // do something 3
    workman.join();
}
```

Comment: @WorldSender - The volatile keyword should be used only for access to hardware.  
Bjarne Stroustrup says as much in TCPPPL4E: Do not use volatile except in low-level code that deals directly with hardware. Do not assume volatile has special meaning in the memory model. It does not. It is not -- as in some later languages -- a synchronization mechanism. To get synchronization, use atomic, a mutex, or a condition_variable. (stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/…)

Comment: As far as I can see, the compiler is free to inline `worker_done` in the code you provided. As far as I can see, volatile would be enough. We gain memory order by using a shared mutex. So what's left is to tell the compiler that the variable can indeed change.

Comment: @WorldSender  - See farther. There are several discussions on this very topic here on SO.  Join one of those discussions.  Spoiler: Even before C++11 laid down the law, a crazed optimizer couldn't mess with worker_done, because there are function calls between tests. Word: Never ever ever contradict Bjarne. He is always right. (And that's not a joke.)

Comment: @WorldSender -  [C++11 standard] ... makes volatile objects suitable for communication with a signal handler, but not with another thread of execution, see std::memory_order.  -- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv

Comment: I see now that locking the mutex is enough to stop the compiler from inlining `worker_done`, sequencing the read and write to it and, most importantly, making the write a visible side effect, preventing the compiler from assuming `worker_done` never changes, even without the addition of volatile, which was my main concern.

Comment: Is worker_done flag really necessary? Its presence only makes the main thread harder to proceed further. In my case, the main thread already couldn't proceed, and that is the problem. How can such a flag soften the situation?

Comment: @Junekey - Yes, it's really necessary. The condition_variable notification can be lost due to a race condition, which is what caused the problem in the first place. It's like when the postman knocks. If no-one is home, it might as well not have happened. The bool variable is like a note left on the door.

Comment: Due to my understanding, notification cannot be lost in this case, because cv.notify_one() can be reached only after getting/releasing the mutex, which can only occur after the main thread have released it, which is done via cv.wait(lg). So cv.notify_one() should have been executed while the main thread is already waiting for it. Is it wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was not arguing. I was asking for your explanation.

Comment: The postman analogy is pretty good, if I may say so myself. We are not supposed to have a prolonged discussion in the comments. Try putting delay between starting the thread and calling cv.wait in the original. main() will lose the race every time, and it will hang.

Comment: Could I ask you further in chatting room?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163171/discussion-between-jive-dadson-and-junekey-jeon).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. The question was totally wrong.
I think the claim "notification should be fired after the main thread have begun to wait" is still right, but the root cause of the hang was **spurious awakening**, as Jive Dadson and Erik Alapää pointed out.

There was a reason I couldn't compile the code w/o optimization options, so I misinterpreted the point of hang because the point where the debugger was pointing to was not very clear. The point of hang was not the line `cv.wait(lg)`. It was somewhere inside `// do something 3`.

I have a flag that is set if `// do something 1` has been succeeded, while it is cleared if an exception is thrown inside `// do something 1`. In `// do something 3`, the flag is checked and if it indicates failure, the main thread calls `worker.get()` to rethrow the exception. Since `// do something 2` is a form of infinite loop, the main thread just hangs if `cv` has waken up spuriously so that the flag is not yet set.

Now it works fine! Thanks everyone.